# Doubt regarding schedulting LocalNotifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doubt regarding scheduling LocalNotifications to fire on Every 2 Days or Every 3 Days.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228468/doubt-regarding-scheduling-localnotifications-to-fire-on-every-2-days-or-every-3)

Hi.

I am having an app in which I have to schedule Local Notifications. Consider a user enters the time 7 AM, then the Notification has to be fired on 7 AM every day (or, ever 2 days, or every 3 days) based on the settings he set. This Notification has to be fired on regular basis until the user turns of the Notification.

My doubt is how to schedule the Notification to fire on every 2 days or every 3 days or every 2 weeks like that? Sorry if this is a very basic question. I am new to Local Notification.