# How to schedule LocalNotifications to fire on Every 2 Days or Every 3 Days.

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having an app in which I have to schedule Local Notifications. Consider a user enters the time 7 AM, then the Notification has to be fired on 7 AM every day (or, ever 2 days, or every 3 days) based on the settings he set. This Notification has to be fired on regular basis until the user turns of the Notification.

My doubt is how to schedule the Notification to fire on every 2 days or every 3 days or every 2 weeks like that? Sorry if this is a very basic question. I am new to Local Notifications.

Comment: Please just edit your original question.

Comment: @Tim Post: I am really sorry. I don't even know how I created two posts? Actually I edited my original question. I didn't create the second post intentionally. It happened by accident. Sorry. Actually this post is my original post. Could you please close the other question and open this question?

Comment: Re-opened, this was actually your second question but does appear to have the answer that you were working with. This is question 5228468, which came after your original question 5228454. I've merged the two keeping this one open, thus removing the duplicate entirely.

Comment: @Tim Post: Thanks Man.. You are sweet... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need you need to make a date list from a start date to end date then need to enter a gap in days for alarms and according to that gap you need to set alarms.

date with time is required for alarms.

see this function this return an array of dates with gap in days

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getDatesArrayBetweenDates:(NSString *)minDate toDate:(NSString *)maxDate freqDays:(NSInteger )dayfreq
{
    // minDate and maxDate represent your date range
    NSMutableArray *resultArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSDate *minDateObject;
    NSDate *maxDateObject;
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    minDateObject=[df dateFromString:minDate];
    maxDateObject=[df dateFromString:maxDate];
    NSInteger dayCount = 0;
    while ( TRUE ) {

        NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents: days toDate: minDateObject options: 0];
        [days setDay: ++dayCount];
        if ( [date compare: maxDateObject] == NSOrderedDescending )
            break;
        // Do something with date like add it to an array, etc.
        NSString *dateForAdd=[df stringFromDate:date];
        //if(![self.dateListArray containsObject:dateForAdd])
            [resultArray addObject:dateForAdd];
    }
    [df release];
    [days release];
    [gregorianCalendar release];

    NSMutableArray *returnableArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger day=0;
    for(int i=0;i<[resultArray count];i++)
    {
       if(day==0)
       {
           [returnableArray addObject:[resultArray objectAtIndex:i]];
       }

        if(day==dayfreq)
            day=0;
        else {
            ++day;
        }

    }
    return returnableArray;
}
```

what you need to pass a start date and end date  in string and the days gap for alarm and this function returns you a array of dates in strings.Now you need to use these date and append your time then make date object by `NSDateFormatter` then set it for `fireDate` of local notification.

see this [link](http://iphoneblog-ishu.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-local-notification-for-alarms.html) for more info

Comment: Yeah,, What I have to do in case if I dont know the end date? Thats my problem.

Comment: Ok at this if i say you need to set alarms everyday then what you do.then also you need a end date or you set alarms for infinite.

Comment: In that case I can set `repeatInterval` to `NSDayCalendarUnit`

Comment: ok,but i dont think with out any end date you can set alarms.you need to hard code the end date after 1 year or 2 year you can set.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [put a NSDate object here];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

This creates a local notification that repeats daily.